# How to trigger collapsable event dynamically for all the data-role="collapsible" present

Tags: jquery

I have got the following fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jWaEv/95/

How can i trigger the click event for all the above class my-collaspible

```
<div data-role="content" class="data">
    <div class="my-collaspible" data-inset="false" data-role="collapsible">
         <h3>Top Stories</h3>

        <p>4 Britons Who Sought to Get to Syria Arrested on Return to UK</p>
        <p>SpaceX Rocket Blasts Off, Then Lands Too Hard on Ocean Barge</p>
        <p>CCTVs in Buses in Kolkata to Make Journey Safer</p>
        <p>Report Fire, Accidents in Goa Via App</p>
    </div>
    <div class="my-collaspible" data-inset="false" data-role="collapsible">
         <h3>Sports Headlines</h3>

        <p>West Indies hold firm after early England wickets</p>
        <p>Rajasthan Royals face Mumbai Indians</p>
        <p>One week to go, no IPL chairman as yet</p>
    </div>
    <div class="my-collaspible" data-inset="false" data-role="collapsible">
         <h3>Movies</h3>

        <p>MOVIE 1----------</p>
        <p>MOVIE 2----------</p>
        <p>MOVIE 3----------</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my-collaspible').on('collapsibleexpand', function () {
        alert('ssss');
    });
});
```

Comment: can you clarify what exactly you want to happen?

Comment: When should it be triggered? Do you want to open all when one is opened or have a separate button to open them all? you need to give more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger the click on the `h3` :

```
$('.my-collaspible h3').click();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jWaEv/96/)

If you mean "previous `.my-collaspible`" by "above class my-collaspible", then this might be what you want :

```
$(this).prev('.my-collaspible').each(function(){
    $(this).children('h3').click()
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jWaEv/98/)

Comment: @PreethiJain Woops, edited my answer. Use `prev` instead of `prevAll` to prevent multiple clicks on the same element

Answer (score 0):

> How to trigger collapsable event dynamically for all the data-role=“collapsible” present

```
$("[data-role='collapsible']").collapsible( "collapse" );
```

> How can i trigger the click event for all the above class my-collaspible

Why would you want to fake a `click` event?